# Django annotate Count include 0 results

Tags: python, django

I have this query to do a count of photos taken by month. It's only returning the values where it's not 0. How can I make it so it will show all months, even when it's 0?

```
today = datetime.date.today()
6months = today - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)
qs = Photo.objects.filter(camera__owner=self,  timestamp__gte=6months).annotate(
    month=ExtractMonth('timestamp'),
).values('month').annotate(
    photos=Count('id')
).order_by('month')
```

Comment: Well since there is no `Photo` object for that month, you can not get 0, but you can "*patch*" the result yourself.

Comment: There is no way to select "months" from database which do not exist there. Unless you build this temporary dataset at runtime by yourself. The other way is to solve this on cliend-side. And you are starting your ORM query with `Photo` model - how could it get photos that aren't there?